# How Do I Connect to a Redis Sentinel that requirespass with ServiceStack.Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

I have a simple redis cluster on my local machine that consists of:

- master on port 3679
- slave on port 6380
- sentinel on port 26379

I am using **ServiceStack.Redis** to connect with no problems so far. Today I added a password to each of them using the `requirepass 42` setting. I can connect to all of them using Redis Desktop Manager fine and everything works as expected.

Using the following code, I get an error when I attempt to connect. Removing the password works as expected.

```
var config = RedisConfiguration.Instance;

Func<string, string> hostFilter = host => string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.SecurityKey)
                                    ? $"{host}?db={config.Database}"
                                    : $"{config.SecurityKey}@{host}?db={config.Database}";


var sentinelHosts = config.SentinelHosts.Select(hostFilter);
var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(sentinelHosts, config.ServiceName)
{
    HostFilter = hostFilter,
    RedisManagerFactory = (master, slaves) => new RedisManagerPool(master)
};

sentinel.OnFailover += manager => Logger?.Warn($"Redis fail over to {sentinel.GetMaster()}");

sentinel.Start()
```

This code throw a RedisException **"No Redis Sentinels were available"** with an inner exception of **"unknown command 'AUTH'"**.

I am not clear if I am using the ServiceStack.Redis library improperly or my Redis cluster configuration is incorrect.

Can some one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HostFilter` to specify the password:

```
sentinel.HostFilter = host => $"{config.SecurityKey}@{host}?db={config.Database}";
```

But when using a password, it needs to be configured everywhere, i.e. in both [Master and Slave configurations](http://sentinel-and-redis-authentication) using:

```
requirepass password
masterauth password
```

The Redis Sentinels also need to be configured to use the same password so it can control the redis instances it's monitoring, which can be configured in your `sentinel.conf` with:

```
sentinel auth-pass mymaster pasword
```

The [windows-password](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-config/tree/master/sentinel3/windows-password) folder in the [redis-config](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-config/) project shows an example of a password-protected Redis Sentinel configuration.

Comment: This looks like it could be the root cause of my issue. I will give it a try and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Ok, you got me moving in the right direction. In the end I had to add `requirepass` and `masterauth` to the config for my master and slave and then turn `protected-mode` to no for my sentinel. That seemed to do the trick.

[Here are my conf files](https://gist.github.com/NotMyself/49bafe59daf68efd18992ce852ac03cb) does this make sense?

Comment: @NotMyself looks ok from here.

Comment: @NotMyself can you share your sentinel config? I am seeing the same issue.